# Why core project vars GitLab CICD not view in subproject?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have core project - stream1

```
https://gitlab.services.com/groups/stream1/-/settings/ci_cd
```

[image]

in stream1 exist other projects for example mvp1.

In mvp1 I add some vars special for mvp1

[image]

I hope on view

```
https://gitlab.services.com/groups/stream1/mvp1/-/settings/ci_cd
```

special vars for mvp1 and vars from core project - stream1.

Why is it not so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question - you are asking why group variables are not visible within the project?

If that is the case just look a little bit lower in you variables settings page. Group variables are visible bellow the project variables in the same page.